# Can one transfer a plan épargne logement (PEL) to another bank as a US permanent resident (green card holder) and French citizen?

Tags: united-states, banking, france, account-transfer

Can one transfer a [plan épargne logement (PEL)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_%C3%A9pargne_logement) to another bank as a US permanent resident (green card holder) and French citizen?